# how we get all images in android 11?

Tags: java, android

I use manage external storage permission for android 11 then how we get all images and videos from external storage?
i use media store but google say you not use manage extrnl storage.

```
private boolean checkStoragePermission() {
    if (SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        return Environment.isExternalStorageManager();
    } else {
        int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        int result1 = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        return result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && result1 == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is scope storage and what is gallery and what is the difference?

Comment: i use media store but google say you not use manage extrnal storage

Comment: Does Google say to not use media store? Or what is the connection? What is the logic here?

Comment: Google say you not use Manage external storage, during form fill. My android version is 30

Comment: Does google say to not use manage external storage because you use the media store? Please tell the real reason! And what do you mean with My in My Android version?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.